# cuda and double-precision floating-point arithmetics

Tags: cuda, gpu

this is what i found: " Cores perform only single-precision floating-point arithmetics. There is 1 double-precision floating-point unit. "

is this true for all compute capabilities (versions) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816992/double-precision-floating-point-in-cuda

Comment: in NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide 4.1 section F.4.1 p.144 is written "32 CUDA cores for integer and floating-point arithmetic operations". by "floating-point" they mean both single and double?

Answer (score 2):

Single and double precision floating point accuracy and performance has continuously evolved and is different for each of the compute capabilities.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf

Comment: Start with Appendix F.1 to see if your GPU supports double.

Comment: right now i am looking for new GPU and i am mainly focused on double precision calculations. so i would like to know if there is GPU which has more then one double-precision floating-point unit per MP.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

section 5.4.1, table 5-1.